# How can I set frequency of each content type with the XML sitemap module?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I use the XML sitemap module (7.x-2.0-beta3) to generate the XML sitemap for my site. The problem is that I cannot set the change frequency of the content types.

In "admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings" I have a "Change frequency" combobox, but this is only for the front page.
I have some other content types and taxonomy tags. How can I change the frequency for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the priority form field is added to the content type form from `xmlsitemap_add_link_bundle_settings()`, which is called by `xmlsitemap_node_form_node_type_form_alter()`.

The first function, in the development snapshot, is using the following form field definitions.

```
  $form['xmlsitemap']['status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Inclusion'),
    '#options' => xmlsitemap_get_status_options(),
    '#default_value' => $bundle_info['status'],
  );

  $form['xmlsitemap']['priority'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Default priority'),
    '#options' => xmlsitemap_get_priority_options(),
    '#default_value' => $bundle_info['priority'],
    '#states' => array(
      'invisible' => array(
        'select[name="xmlsitemap[status]"]' => array('value' => '0'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

The form field for the priority is invisible when the "status" field is set to 0.

Comment: So priority = frequency?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble with "yearly" and "never" coming up unexpectedly under the `<changefreq>` tag. This is a separate setting from `<priority>` - it's a different XML tag and they don't seem to be related based on what you choose for priority.

I wish I found a better solution that did actually allow you to control this setting in the UI per content type. But since this does not seem to exist, I simply disabled `changefreq` completely:

- Go to /admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings
- expand Advanced Settings
- uncheck Change frequency

Probably better to allow google to determine for itself how frequently to index in most cases.  And if you need more control over crawling to try and control it using Webmaster Tools instead of the changefreq tag.